# Can't copy HTML from a template in Marketing Cloud -- but, was able to before -- what gives?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, html

Previously, when reviewing the HTML in a template, one could highlight all of the code to copy/paste the code for other uses... however, when we try now the code cannot be copied.  I need to pull a copy of the code before the email deploys - is this possible now?  If yes, how?  If no - ARGH!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reference this KI: [Unable to copy HTML contents from Code View - template based emails](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001YqGuQAK&title=unable-to-copy-html-contents-from-code-view-template-based-emails)

> Summary
> Currently, it is difficult to copy code directly out of the code view of a >Template-Based email.
>
> Repro
>
> 1. Create/edit template-based email
> 2. Switch to Code View
> 3. Try to highlight the code and copy
>
> Workaround
>
> 1. Highlight the code
> 2. Right-click and select: Create Code Snippet
> 3. Code can be selected and copied from the modal